# onclick of button need to add state value -12 with 50 and the result value ie(38) should update to dest value and source value should become 0

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

onclick of button need to add state value -12 with 50 and the result value ie(38) should update to destcommomRowData value and srcommomRowData value should become 0

is it possible to achieve

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  let srcommomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: -12 } } } },
  };

  let destcommomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: 50 } } } },
  };
  const [srcdata, srcsetData] = useState(srcommomRowData);
  const [destdata, destsetData] = useState(destcommomRowData);
  const updateData = () => {};
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Testing</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateData}> Click </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't need to update variables. You should update state only - the only reason why you might want to store the initial data in variables outside of state is for readability.

To accomplish your goal, you need to set destination data state value using the src data state value, and then update the src data state value:

```js
const Test = () => {
  const srcCommomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: -12 } } } }
  };

  const destCommomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: 50 } } } }
  };
  const [srcData, setSrcData] = useState(srcCommomRowData);
  const [destData, setDestData] = useState(destCommomRowData);

  const updateData = () => {
    setDestData(destData => {
      const updatedData = { ...destData };
      updatedData[2020].firstLevel.children.secondLevel.value +=
        srcData[2020].firstLevel.children.secondLevel.value;
      return updatedData;
    });
    setSrcData(srcData => {
      const updatedData = { ...srcData };
      updatedData[2020].firstLevel.children.secondLevel.value = 0;
      return updatedData;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Testing</div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateData}> Click </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

See this working example that displays the values: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-franklin-e1l9s?file=/src/Test.js:42-1213